# Django TemplateDoesNotExist at '/' with outside app

Tags: python, html, reactjs, django, path

Lately i've been trying to connect my django application that serves as an API to a react app that will work as the frontend (the react app was made with vite by the way). The issue that i'm having is that, no matter what i change in the index.html (frontend), urls.py or settings.py (backend) i always get the same error: `TemplateDoesNotExist at /`.
This would be my folder hierarchy, considering the react folder and django folder are at the same level (don't mind the name of the folders inside de hierarchy, i need to change them).

- React (front end):

[image: React (frontend) hierarchy]

This is the `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="https://va.exeiot.com/static/assets/media/logos/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
     <!--Fuenes Material UI-->
     <link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
   />

   <!--Fuentes EXEIOT-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700">
    <title>Video Analitica</title>
    <!--Linea de refereencia para que el navegador pueda encontrar index.algo.js-->
    <base href="/dist/">
    <!--Fin referencia-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Django (backed, API):

[image: Django (backed, API) hierarchy]

In the Django directory the folder "backend" contains the settings of the django project and the folder "frontend" contains the api, views and models.
This are the contents of:

- settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import environ


# Environ
root = environ.Path(__file__) - 2
SITE_ROOT = root()
env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
ENV_PATH = env.str('ENV_PATH', default=SITE_ROOT + '/.env')
environ.Env.read_env(ENV_PATH)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
REACT_BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

# App url
APP_URL = env('APP_URL')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'not putting that here'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig',   Modificado para compatibilidad con exe-va-plataforma-ui
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'frontend',                       # Añadido para compatibilidad con exe-va-plataforma-ui
    'rest_framework'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(REACT_BASE_DIR, 'exeiot-va-plataforma-ui', 'dist')],# Modificado para compatibilidad con exe-va-plataforma-ui
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                #'frontend.context_processors.app_url',                Modificado para compatibilidad con exe-va-plataforma-ui
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': env('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Santiago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

DATE_FORMAT = 'd-m-Y'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%d-%m-%Y"],
    "DATE_FORMAT": "%d-%m-%Y",
}


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'# Modificado para compatibilidad con exe-va-plataforma-ui
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(REACT_BASE_DIR, 'exeiot-va-plataforma-ui', 'dist', 'assets')]# Creado para compatibilidad con exe-va-plataforma-ui
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ["django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler"]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

- backend/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from frontend.views import index


""" Modificado para compatibilidad con exeiot-va-plataforma-ui """
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), Comentado para compatibilidad con exeiot-va-plataforma-ui 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)#\
#              + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

- frontend/urls.py:

````
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from frontend.forms import UserLoginForm
from . import views
from . import api
from .api_custom import api_dashboard
from .api_custom import api_entrenamiento


# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)
router.register(r'detecciones', views.DeteccionViewSet)
router.register(r'profiles', views.ProfileViewSet)
router.register(r'metadatas', views.MetadataViewSet)
router.register(r'datasets', views.DatasetViewSet)
router.register(r'modelos', views.ModeloViewSet)
router.register(r'clases', views.ClaseViewSet)
router.register(r'auditorias', views.AuditoriaViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),# ______________________________________________
    # path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),                            | Comentado para compatibilidad
    # path('procesamiento/', views.procesamiento, name='procesamiento'),                | con exeiot-va-plataforma-ui
    # path('entrenamiento/', views.entrenamiento, name='entrenamiento'),                |
    # path('entrenamiento_test/', views.entrenamiento_test, name='entrenamiento_test'), |
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/datasets/add', api_entrenamiento.datasets_add, name='api_entrenamiento.datasets_add'),
    path('api/modelos/add', api_entrenamiento.modelos_add, name='api_entrenamiento.modelos_add'),
    path('api/dashboard/general', api_dashboard.dashboard_general, name='api_dashboard.dashboard_general'),
    path('api/dashboard/distribucion', api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion, name='api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion'),
    path('api/dashboard/distribucion_clases', api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion_clases, name='api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion_clases'),
    path('api/dashboard/distribucion_turnos', api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion_turnos, name='api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion_turnos'),
    path('api/dashboard/distribucion_usuarios', api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion_usuarios, name='api_dashboard.dashboard_distribucion_usuarios'),
    path('api/dashboard/detalle_metadatas', api_dashboard.dashboard_detalle_metadatas, name='api_dashboard.dashboard_detalle_metadatas'),
    path('api/detecciones/metadata', api.detection_2_metadata, name='api.detection_2_metadata'),
    path('api/detecciones/upload', api.upload_detections, name='api.upload_detections'),
    path('api/detections/tree', api.detections_tree, name='api.detections_tree'),
    path('api/detections/data', api.detections_data, name='api.detections_data'),
    path('api/metadatas/data', api.detections_data, name='api.metadatas_data'),
    path('api/detections/params', api.detections_params, name='api.detections_params'),# __________
    # path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html',|Comentado para compatibilidad
    #                                                      authentication_form=UserLoginForm)),    | con exeiot-va-plataforma-ui
]```
I read on a similar post that i probably need to add my react folder to installed apps, but i wouldn't know how to do that since the fact that the react folder is outside of the django root.
Any help is welcome and thanks in advance.
````